# How to pass object(or Associative Array) as value of attribute to my web-component

Tags: javascript, html, object, web-component

I am making vanilla-js web-component and need to pass object to attribute as its value, but every time it takes it as string.

I am able to pass string to attributes of my components, but know I need to pass an object.

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

const template = document.createElement('template');

class TabelComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.content);
    }
    
    get content() {
        return this.getAttribute("content")
    }
}

window.customElements.define('table-component', TabelComponent);
```

```html
<table-component content=obj></table-component>
```

My attribute "content" should take obj as object not as string. I should get
`{ name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };` in console

Comment: html attributes are strings. If you want to get that string as object, use `JSON.parse()`.

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking for is normally the job of a framework.

It is best to pass objects into Web Components through properties and not attributes:

### Property

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

class TabelComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = '<h1>your DOM here</h1><pre id="content"></pre>';
  }

  connectedCallback() {
  }

  set content(val) {
    this._content = val;
    // render changes
    let el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#content');
    el.textContent = JSON.stringify(this._content,0,2);
  }
  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('table-component', TabelComponent);

setTimeout(() => {
  let el = document.getElementById('mine');
  el.content = obj;
}, 10);
```

```html
<table-component id="mine"></table-component>
```

### Data URI

BUT if you really want to pass something in through an attribute then look at using the standards of Data URIs. (https://devdocs.io/http/basics_of_http/data_uris)

This is done by always using `fetch` to get your data and treat the `content` attribute like it is a URL. This allows you to load data from a URL and still allows you to directly pass in JSON data.

> **Your data does need to be fully JSON compliant and also needs to be URL encoded.**

It is easiest to use the `observedAttributes` static function to define the attribute you want to watch and then `attributeChangedCallback` to know when the attribute changes. Be aware that the `newVal` will be `null` when the attribute is removed and you need to handle that differently.

The example below is simple and would need some error checking. But it shows how to use a Data URI to accomplish the task.

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

class TabelComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = '<h1>your DOM here</h1><pre id="content"></pre>';
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['content'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      if (newVal === null) {
        // Attribute was removed
        this._content = null;
        this.render();
      }
      else {
        fetch(newVal).then(
          (res) => res.json()
        ).then(
          (data) => {
            this._content = data;
            this.render();
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }  

  connectedCallback() {
  }

  render() {
    let el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#content');
    el.textContent = JSON.stringify(this._content,0,2);
  }

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('table-component', TabelComponent);
```

```html
<table-component content="data:application/json,%7B%22name%22%3A%22John%22%2C%22age%22%3A30%2C%22city%22%3A%22New%20York%22%7D" id="mine"></table-component>
```

One huge advantage of doing it this way, using fetch, is that you can also supply a URL instead of using the Data URI. This allows you to get data from anywhere and still use it.

This is also the way that the various built-in tags work. Like **<img src="URL or Data URI">**, **<audio src="URL or Data URI">** and **<video src="URL or Data URI">**

### JSON in attribute

If you really don't want to use the full Data URI the you can trim the code down a little to this:

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

class TabelComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = '<h1>your DOM here</h1><pre id="content"></pre>';
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['content'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal !== newVal) {
      if (newVal === null) {
        // Attribute was removed
        this._content = null;
        this.render();
      }
      else {
        this._content = JSON.parse(newVal);
        this.render();
      }
    }
  }  

  connectedCallback() {
  }

  render() {
    let el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#content');
    el.textContent = JSON.stringify(this._content,0,2);
  }

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('table-component', TabelComponent);
```

```html
<table-component content="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;John&quot,&quot;age&quot;:30,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;New York&quot;}" id="mine"></table-component>
```

You may notice that this does require you to encode the double quotes into `&quot;` to prevent an accidental end-of-attribute-value.

Of course you can always force your attribute to use single quotes and then not need to escape the double quotes, but you would need to escape any single quotes:

`<table-component content='{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}' id="mine"></table-component>`

### Variable value in Attribute

What I really think you are asking for is the ability to pass the value of a variable into the Component by setting the variable name in the attribute:

`<table-component content='<variable name>' id="mine"></table-component>`

This can be done, but you are now stepping into the realm of a framework.

The problem is what is the scope of that variable? Is it a global? Is it a member variable? Is it something else?

If you only want to use Global variables then this is pretty easy. *But very limited!*:

> **I DO NOT RECCOMMEND THIS METHOD.** It is sloppy and prone to problems.

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };

class TabelComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = '<h1>your DOM here</h1><pre id="content"></pre>';
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['content'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (newVal === null) {
      // Attribute was removed
      this._content = null;
      this.render();
    }
    else {
      this._content = window[newVal];
      this.render();
    }
  }  

  connectedCallback() {
  }

  render() {
    let el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#content');
    el.textContent = JSON.stringify(this._content,0,2);
  }

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
}

window.customElements.define('table-component', TabelComponent);
```

```html
<table-component content="obj"></table-component>
```

This will not auto-update when the value for `obj` changes. To get the Component to re-read the variable you need to change the value of the attribute. But this is more complicated then just setting the property.

### Multiple Properties

No code here, but the simplest version might be is creating multiple properties and each one affects a portion of your DOM. Then you can set each property when it needs to change instead of resetting everything all the time.

Comment: This is an excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.stringify()` with `Element.setAttribute()` to transform your object into a string:

```
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" }
document.querySelector( 'table-component' ).setAttribute( 'content', JSON.stringify( obj ) )
```

And use `JSON.parse()` with `Element.getAttribute()` to transform the string attribute into an object:

```
get content() {
    return JSON.parse( this.getAttribute( 'content' ) )
}
```

```js
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
document.querySelector( 'table-component' ).setAttribute( 'content', JSON.stringify(obj) )

const template = document.createElement('template');

class TabelComponent extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.content);
    }
    
    get content() {
        return JSON.parse( this.getAttribute( "content" ) )
    }
}

window.customElements.define('table-component', TabelComponent);
```

```html
<table-component content=''></table-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the object to a JSON string, like:

```
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
var objString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```
<table-component id="h" content="objString "></table-component>
```

And then in your web component should parse it back to your object

```
var obj = JSON.parse(this.content);
```